# Setup a local configuration file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Probably my English is not the best,i will try to re-explain.

```
SERVER ROOT
    —> global_application_folder
    -> global_system_folder

    —> app_1
        - index.php
        - local_config_file.php
        - local_database_file.php

    -> app_2
        - index.php
        - local_config_file.php
        - local_database_file.php

    -> app_3
        - index.php
        - local_config_file.php
        - local_database_file.php
```

In any folder app_N i have "index.php" that takes care to say where to find the application and system folders.

"local_config_file", it should serve to change some settings in "config/config.php" like: $config['base_url'], $config['sess_cookie_name'], etc, etc.

"local_database_file", it should serve to change some settings in "config/database.php".

Everything works, now i have to find a good way to override the configurations i need to change for each app.

In the previous link: http://caseymclaughlin.com/articles/setup-a-local-configuration-file-in-codeigniter, (which explains what I need ), it describes a way but it does not work, perhaps because dated.

Doing various tests, the only working way i've found is to add, for example, at the end of the "config/config.php"

```
include_once(FCPATH . 'local_config_file.php');
```

including the file (in this case "local_config_file.php"), that is not found in the "global_appliacation_folder/config" folder, but within the various folders app_N, that's why FCPATH in the path of inclusion.

So if i will be app_1, the included file ("local_config_file.php"), will be inside the folder app_1

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to make it all separate repositories and use and dependency manager. eg. composer for php.

With that approach get better control of individual applications, with easy way how to distribute changes in the core.
This way you can also leave old apps - to depend on older version of the core fixed at a specific version

You can have

- **core repo**
- **test app 1 repo**

  > depends on core repo
- **test app 2 repo**

  > depends on core repo and some other repo
- **test app 3 repo**

  > depends on core repo legacy version

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand.
Ok for composer but i do not see the usefulness of it in this case, dependency management is not the problem.

If i have the application and system folders out of the folders of the various app, via the index.php of each app i can decide which version to use, is not dependency problem.


All apps will be equal in every way, what I have to change are some configurations like config.php or database.php